# How to remove non numeric charcter from numeric string?

Tags: perl

I have following data. I would like to print last column without non numeric character from a string. Kindly help me

```
N THR K 149A
CA THR K 149A
C THR K 149A
O THR K 149A
CB THR K 149A
OG1 THR K 149A
CG2 THR K 149A
N SER K 149B
CA SER K 149B
C SER K 149B
O SER K 149B
CB SER K 149B
```

for solving the above problem I have tried by following program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open(F1, "$ARGV[0]") or die;
chomp(@arr=<F1>);
close F1;

for($i=0;$i<=$#arr;$i++)
{
    @pdb=split(/\h/,$arr[$i]);
    if($pdb[3] =~ /[A-Z]/*$);{
        $pdb[3] =~ s/\D//g;
        print "$pdb[1] $pdb[2] $pdb[3]\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You are printing the last 3 columns, not just the last column. Also, this code looks to do what you wanted (even though it could be improved by a great deal), is there a problem?

Comment: Is `/[A-Z]/*$;{` a typo, where you accidentally placed the slash two steps to the left?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, unless this is a typo, it is the thing wrong with your code.

```
if($pdb[3] =~ /[A-Z]/*$);{
```

In this code, you have placed the slash `/` in the middle of your regex, and also placed a semi-colon there which does not belong anywhere on that line. Also, you are using `*` as the quantifier, which will not work as intended, because it will allow a match on the empty string (zero matches), which will match *all*  strings. The correct line is:

```
if($pdb[3] =~ /[A-Z]+$/) {
```

However, this entire line is incorrect, when taken in context:

```
if($pdb[3] =~ /[A-Z]*$/) {
    $pdb[3] =~ s/\D//g;
```

Here you only remove non-digits if upper case letters are found. Besides the fact that you are checking for two different things, you do not need to check before substituting, because a substitution will not do anything if it does not match. So... something like this:

```
if ($foo =~ /A/) {
     $foo =~ s/A//g;
```

is completely redundant, because `s/A//g` will not do anything unless there is already an `A` in the string.

---

Also, a few more things you should know:

Always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

As it will help you prevent a lot of simple mistakes.

Use three argument open, with lexical file handle, and check the return value including the error:

```
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!";
```

You do not need to quote variables, such as with `"$ARGV[0]"`. You leave out the quotes: `$ARGV[0]`.

You are using a C-style for loop. Using a Perl-style loop is preferred, in my opinion:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#arr)
```

But you should not be using array indexes unless you need the indexes themselves, so the better loop is:

```
for my $line (@arr)
```

But again, as a general rule, it is better to read a file line-by-line than slurping it into an array. For this purpose you would use a `while` loop, which iterates over the file handle instead of exhausting it all at once:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    # process line $_
}
```

Using `/\h/` as the field delimiter for `split` is wrong, unless you intended that consecutive whitespace indicates empty fields. The default split is `' '`, which splits on multiple whitespace `/\s+/`, and also strips leading whitespace. With CSV data, it is possibly correct to split on single delimiters, but in that case you should use the specific delimiter, and not a character class like `\h`.

Like I said before, using the `*` quantifier in a regex match is horribly wrong. You might notice that a regex such as `/[A-Z]*/` matches anything if you try it out: `perl -lnwe 'print /[A-Z]*/ ? "match!" : "no match";'` That is because it is allowed to match the empty string, and all strings match the empty string.

And like I also said, you do not need to check before you substitute. At least not for the same thing. So, when simplified, your code becomes:

```
open my $fh, "<", $ARGV[0] or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!";

while (<$fh>) {                # short for while ($_ = <$fh>)
    chomp;                     # short for chomp($_)
    my @fields = split;        # short for split(' ', $_)
    $fields[3] =~ s/\D//g;
    print "@fields[1,2,3]\n";  # quoting an array inserts spaces between elements
}
```

Note that I used an array slice, where we only use the elements with the indicated elements. You can also write this such as:

```
print join(" ", $fields[1], $fields[2], $fields[3]), "\n";
```

You might note also that this is possible to achieve using a one-liner:

```
perl -anlwe '$F[3] =~ s/\D//g; print "@F[1,2,3]"'
```

The `-a` switch autosplits the line on whitespace, storing the fields in `@F`. The `-l` switch chomps the line and adds newline to print. And the `-n` switch reads input from STDIN or argument files, whichever is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if m/(\d+)\D$/' datafile
```